# How to set an array to ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to set an array into a `wxListCtrl`.

Similar to the `Set` function when using `wx.ListBox` or the `SetItems` function when using `wx.ComboBox`.

On the wxpython API there only seems to be an `Append` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to do this in the API other than just using a loop. There is a weird example in the wxPython demo for the ListCtrl where they somehow set a dict as the data for the list control. You might like that. Alternatively, I enjoy using the ObjectListView widget (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ObjectListView) as I find it easier to use anyway.

In wxPython 2.9, there's the new DVC_ListCtrl, but it also probably needs a loop.